# Fails to build Yaws on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, yaws

I downloaded Yaws 1.98, but when executing `./configure && make` if fails with the message provided below:

```
gcc -c -g -O2 -I/usr/include/security -m64 -I/usr/include/pam -DHAVE_SENDFILE -I"/usr/local/lib/erlang/usr/include" -I/usr/include/pam/  epam.c
epam.c:2:10: fatal error: 'pam_appl.h' file not found
#include <pam_appl.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [epam.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this? is there any other way I can run the latest version of Yaws on Mac OS X 10.9?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `pam_appl.h` include file is normally found in `/usr/include/security` on OS X 10.6 and higher, and that's installed as part of the Command Line Tools installation. Normally you would run `sudo xcode-select --install` from your Terminal command line to install the command line tools, but that sometimes fails — see [Failed to install command line tools on OSX Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691701/failed-to-install-command-line-tools-on-osx-mavericks) for details and workarounds. Of course, you can always download the command line tools install package from [Apple's Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) (registration required).

Since your error message shows you already have gcc, be aware that it's also installed as part of the command line tools installation.

Answer (score 0):

This shows that pam development library is not available in you mac OS for YAWS to get compiled successfully.

I do not have experience in installing pam-devel in mac but on unix based machine yum install pam-devel would help me installing. Please check if something helps here http://www.webmin.com/udownload.html